# firefox and opera having trouble with position fixed

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using one of these typical position:fixed "scroll to top" links that, via jquery, fades in as you manually scroll down, and fades back out if you manually scroll back up. When the link is clicked, it animate-scrollTop's you to the top of the site.

The css issue is that, when you click the link in opera-or-firefox, the css switches from bottom:10px to top:0px, and no scrollTop occurs unless you click it again.

If you change it to top:0 in the stylesheet, the link works fine. But try bottom:10px (or anything other than top:0) and the act of clicking it results in it changing to top:0 again.
It's as though FF & O do not allow anything other than top:0px.

Any ideas?

Here's the CSS -

```
a#scrollup{
display:none;
width:51px;
height:51px;
-moz-opacity:.7;
opacity:.7;
zoom:1;
filter:alpha(opacity=70);
position:fixed;
overflow:hidden;
text-indent:100%;
white-space: nowrap;
z-index:1001;
bottom:10px;
right:10px;
background: url('images/ui.totop.png') no-repeat;
-webkit-transition:opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition:opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition:opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
        transition:opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

a#scrollup:hover{
-moz-opacity:.9;
opacity:.9;
filter:alpha(opacity=90);
}
a#scrollup:active{bottom:8px}
```

Here's the script -

```
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('a#scrollup').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('a#scrollup').hide('fast');  
        }
    }); 

    $('a#scrollup').click(function(){
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600, 'easeInExpo');
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright the only fix I could think of was to give the anchor a div wrapper, and apply
position:fixed and bottom:10px to it, rather than to the anchor/link.

New CSS:

```
div#scrollup {
display:none;
position:fixed;
z-index:1001;
bottom:10px;
right:10px;
}

div#scrollup a{
overflow:hidden;
text-indent:100%;
white-space: nowrap;
width:51px;
height:51px;
-moz-opacity:.7;
opacity:.7;
zoom:1;
filter:alpha(opacity=70);
background: url('images/ui.totop.png') no-repeat;
-webkit-transition:opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition:opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition:opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
        transition:opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

div#scrollup a:hover{
-moz-opacity:.9;
opacity:.9;
filter:alpha(opacity=90);
}
div#scrollup a:active{bottom:8px}
```

altered jquery:

```
     $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('div#scrollup').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('div#scrollup').hide('fast');  
        }
    }); 

    $('div#scrollup a').click(function(){
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600, 'easeInExpo');
        return false;
    });
```

So it needed a wrapper.